# Firebase - GetTokenResult, getExpirationTimestamp() not found

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying below code to obtain token and its expiration time for a Firebase user:

```
fun refreshToken(apiBlock: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    if (firebaseUser != null) {
        firebaseUser.getIdToken(false)
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        generatedToken = task.result.token
                        val tokenExpirationTime = task.result.expirationTimestamp
                        apiBlock?.invoke()
                    } else {
                        // Handle error -> task.getException();
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

However I am getting compilation error at following line:

```
val tokenExpirationTime = task.result.expirationTimestamp
```

When I tried to check the existence of this method in decompiled class, I could not get any such method:

```
package com.google.firebase.auth;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Hide;

public class GetTokenResult {
    private String zzeia;

    @Hide
    public GetTokenResult(String var1) {
        this.zzeia = var1;
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getToken() {
        return this.zzeia;
    }
}
```

However as per [GetTokenResult class reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GetTokenResult) there should be getExpirationTimestamp() method:

> getExpirationTimestamp() Returns the time in milliseconds since epoch
>   at which this ID token will expire

Am I missing anything over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it, the code compiles well.
This is firebase version in my project, try to set the same

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```